# Python: Extract float from string of standard form

Tags: python, command-line, floating-point, argv

I want to take a command line argument, `argv[2]`, which will always be of the form `split_pct=x` where x is a specified float. To clarify, here's some valid examples: `split_pct=90.0` or `split_pct=55.23`. For the given input, how could I extract that float?

Running Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

Resolved - because the string is of a standard form, we can get only the values after `split_pct=`. `split_pct=` is 10 chars, so

`x = float(sys.argv[2][10:]`

works.

Comment: Didn't you say in your question that split_pct is assigned a float such as 90.0 or 55.23? Why would those be 10 chars long? In any case consider my answer as well.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the context well enough - argv[2] will be `split_pct=x` where x is a float, but `split_pct=` is still a part of the argument. Hence, argv[2] could be `split_pct=77.5`. Next step is to grab only the float part, so using `[10:]` to skip the `split_pct=` part

Comment: Although this works, it is not a good idea to do things like that. As you can see in my answer, there is no need to assign values to variable in the command line. This will change according to the variable length and will cause you to have extra filtering code. Instead, you should either do what I said, or use helper variables to make the command line more readable. See the link I posted in my answer for more details.

Comment: @lbragile: There is nothing wrong with accepting arguments in the form name=value, and, in various situations, it is a good design. For example, when a program has many things that could be adjusted, it may be convenient to the user to let them list the settings they want in the form of these assignments.

Answer (score -1):

**You want to look into type casting:**

```
x = 1.0
y = 2*x # 2.0
z = 2/x # 2.0

x = str(1.0)
y = 2*x # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'
z = 2/x # TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'int' and 'str'

w = float(x) # Cast to float
y = 2*w # 2.0
z = 2/w # 2.0
```

More information can be found [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/type-conversion-and-casting).

**To use an argument from the command line:**

```
import sys
split_pct = sys.argv[2]
```

This works if your command is this:

```
python3 script.py first_var 90.0
```

Since the script name counts as `sys.argv[0]`, see [here](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/system/python-sys-argv) for more details: